# Do you know a good concurrency puzzles website?

Tags: java, concurrency, puzzle

I'm learning Java concurrency and looking for interesting exercises and puzzles website (or other sources) to help me learn the API.

Thanks guys for the responses. I was more thinking that problems and exercises on a University website as part of course material for example, if you know such links that would be helpful.

BTW, I have both suggested books and yes they are a very good source.

Thank you.

Comment: There is nothing better than [Java Concurrency in Practice](http://www.amazon.com/Java-Concurrency-Practice-Brian-Goetz/dp/0321349601) book...

Answer (score 4):

The best source of puzzles in general. http://www.javapuzzlers.com/ Some of these are about concurrency.  The best book to read is JCP already mentioned.